# Access value of parameter of type 'Agent' in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

The model I am working on is set up as follows. It contains four agent types:

1. Patient
2. SmallHospital
3. MediumHospital
4. BigHospital

. All these agents are located in Main. SmallHospital and MediumHospital agents are connected in a network to BigHospitals using [link to agent objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilBB9.png) e.g.: `mediumHospitalLink` and `bigHospitalLink`.

When generated, Patients move, via a statechart in Patient, to nearest hospital agent (regardless of type, using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG5tp.png) function in Patient). The hospital agent to which the Patient moved to is stored in a parameter in Patient called `p_myFirstHospital`. [This parameter](http://%5B2%5D:%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1rN7.png) has type 'Agent' as I do not beforehand to which hospital type the agent will be move to. This results in no error and functions as expected.[image]

However, I want to move the Patient-agent to a second hospital after a while. If the Patient is currently in a smallHospital, it should move to the mediumHospital to which the smallHospital is linked to, and likewise, if the Patient is in a mediumHospital, it should move to a bigHospital to which the mediumHospital is linked to.

I expected that I would be able to call from within Patient the following code to access those agents:
`p_myFirstHospital.mediumHospitalLink.getConnectedAgent();`

or through [a simple function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP3ag.png) I created. It should retrieve the agent from the `Link to agents` located in the hospital agent stored in `p_myFirstHospital`.

Unfortunately, this does not work. The compiler returns the following error message:
`Description: smallHospitalLink cannot be resolved or is not a field. Location: model/Patient/f_DetermineSecondHospital - Function`

Am I missing some Java or AnyLogic subtleties? Your help and suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because p_myFirstHospital is of type Agent

So you need to make java magic as follows:

```
case1:
p_mySecondHospital=((SmallHospital)p_myFirstHospital).mediumHospitalLink.getConnectedAgent();
case2:
p_mySecondHospital=((MediumHospital)p_myFirstHospital).mediumHospitalLink.getConnectedAgent();
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, even on a Saturday! That indeed solved it :-) I had tried `(SmallHospital)p_myFirstHospital.mediumHospitalLink.getConnectedAgent();`,which lacks the extra pair of enclosing brackets.